# how to send ObjectID with ajax to backend (Node.JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

font-end code(HTML, Javascript) I want to make delete button but i can't send ObjectID with ajax

```
var retName = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/delete",
          data: 
            {'id' : ObjectId(retName)}
          ,
          success: function() {

          },
          error: function(textstatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('text status' + textstatus + ', err ' + errorThrown);
          }
        });
```

back-end code(Node.js)

```
app.post('/delete', function(require, response) {
  db.open(function(error, db) {
  db.collection('infodb', function(error, collection) {
  var doc = require.body;
  console.log(ObjectId(doc))
  collection.remove(doc, function() {
    db.close();
  });
});
  });
});
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot send body params in delete method. Instead of sending id in body params, use url params or query parameters to send id to api method.

```
app.post('/delete/:id', function(request, response) { 
  db.open(function(error, db) {
    db.collection('infodb', function(error, collection) {
      var doc = ObjectId(request.params.id); 
      console.log(ObjectId(doc)) 
      collection.remove({_id:doc} , function() {
        db.close();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your NodeJS, it should be

```
app.post('/delete', function(request, response) {
  db.open(function(error, db) {
    db.collection('infodb', function(error, collection) {
      var doc = request.body.id;
      console.log(doc)
      collection.remove(doc, function() {
        db.close();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

since you want the parameter `id`.

Also since it is already the object `ObjectId` I don't understand why you would get the id of that object.

If this doesn't work, did you try passing another variable instead of your ObjectId?

Comment: thank you for answer but I already solved this problem.

Comment: Btw. I'm pretty sure it is `function(request, response) {}` not `function(require, response) {}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you using "POST" method to delete data. Why cant you just define delete method and give a proper name to api. Because API name can not be a verb and here delete is the verb. You can define your code like this and i am going to give this api name as "user". you can change it

```
var retName = $(this).data("row-id");
    $.ajax({
          type: "DELETE",  //Delete method here 
          url: '/user/'+retName ,
          success: function(data) {
console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(textstatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('text status' + textstatus + ', err ' + errorThrown);
          }
        });
```

and in node js

```
app.delete('/user/{id}', function(req, response) {
 console.log(req.params.id); //this will give you id
  db.open(function(error, db) {
  db.collection('infodb', function(error, collection) {
  //var doc = require.body;
  console.log(ObjectId(doc))
  collection.remove(doc, function() {
    db.close();
  });
});
  });
});
```